# Batch, Little bug in my script (findstr) that thinks the numbers 1, 10, 100 & 1000 are the same -_-

Tags: batch-file, findstr

Thank you, You answered my first question perfectly, I do need to use findstr /f /c: rather than findstr /c:.

as the question I asked has been answered, I feel that the topic is solved and the "tick" was well deserved :P I have moved onto another post to help solve the new problem I'm having.

```
@echo off
echo --------------------
echo Lottery Program
echo --------------------
echo.
echo.
echo These are the Taken numbers.
type takennumbersnice.txt
echo.
echo.
set /p name= Please type the players name 
:thestart
echo ---------------------------
set /p multinum1= Please type their first number [01-100] 
findstr /x /c:%multinum1% takennumbersnice.txt && (
echo This number has already been taken! & pause && goto thestart
) || (
echo %multinum1%>> takennumbers.txt & goto next) 
:next
:thestart2
echo ---------------------------
set /p multinum2= Now type their second number [0 if they only picked 1 number] 
if '%multinum2%'=='0' (
goto endofnums
) else (
goto 3
)
:3
findstr /x /c:%multinum2% takennumbersnice.txt && (
echo This number has already been taken! & pause  && goto thestart2
) || (
echo %multinum2%>> takennumbers.txt &goto next2)
:next2
:thestart3
echo ---------------------------
set /p multinum3= Now type their third number [0 if they only picked 2 numbers] 
if '%multinum3%'=='0' (
goto endofnums
) else (
goto 4
)
:4
findstr /x /c:%multinum3% takennumbersnice.txt && (
echo This number has already been taken! & pause  && goto thestart3
) || (
echo %multinum3%>> takennumbers.txt &goto next3)
:next3
:thestart4
echo ---------------------------
set /p multinum4= Now type their fourth number [0 if they only picked 3 numbers] 
if '%multinum4%'=='0' (
goto endofnums
) else (
goto 5
)
:5
findstr /x /c:%multinum4% takennumbersnice.txt && (
echo This number has already been taken! & pause  && goto thestart4
) || (
echo %multinum4%>> takennumbers.txt &goto next4)
:next4
:thestart5
echo ---------------------------
set /p multinum5= Now type their fifth number [0 if they only picked 4 numbers] 
if '%multinum5%'=='0' (
goto endofnums
) else (
goto 6
)
:6
echo ---------------------------
findstr /x /c:%multinum5% takennumbersnice.txt && (
echo This number has already been taken! & pause  && goto thestart5
) || (
echo %multinum5%>> takennumbers.txt)
:endofnums
set number= %multinum1% %multinum2% %multinum3% %multinum4% %multinum5%
echo %name% has chosen the number[s] %number%
echo %name% %number% >> lottery.txt
sort < takennumbers.txt > takennumbersnice.txt
echo press any key to exit
pause > nul
exit
```

Comment: I've just changed the code to include /x as asked below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you omit the /X-Switch for findstr (exact match), 
findstr will find' a "**10**" also in "**10**0" and "**10**00".

try `findstr /x /c:`(...)

Comment: I just tried this, it works but now it doesn't say if any number has been taken! gah, where am I going wrong

Comment: i removed all *"* (for visual purposes) and it works like a charm. one thing to mention: "Start" is never a good name for a label, as this is also a command within batch.

Comment: I've started another topic, it's unfair of me to keep changing the question...you answered my first and second questions and you only got one tick for it :P, consider this topic answered! You've really helped me